# GetSendEndpoint expects an address as parameter, what to pass when it connects to a 3 node clustered RMQ?

Tags: c#, masstransit

As below, `GetSendEndpoint` expects `Uri address` as parameter. But we have a RMQ cluster with 3 nodes (3 addresses), what do I have to pass with `GetSendEndpoint` then?

```
namespace MassTransit
{
  public interface ISendEndpointProvider : ISendObserverConnector
  {
    Task<ISendEndpoint> GetSendEndpoint(Uri address);
  }
}
```

Bus connects to the cluster as follows:

```
//cluster is a list of strings containing the cluster node hostnames

_mtBus = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(busFactoryConfig =>
{
    busFactoryConfig.Host(new Uri($"rabbitmq://{cluster.First()}:5671"), hostConfig =>
    {
        hostConfig.Username(_username);
        hostConfig.Password(_password);
        hostConfig.UseSsl(x => { });
        hostConfig.UseCluster(c =>
        {
            foreach (var node in cluster)
            {
                c.Node(node);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When configuring a cluster, the host "address" is a logical name, and is not used to connect to any RabbitMQ nodes. That's the name you should use. Change your configuration as shown:

```
var bus = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(cfg =>
{
    cfg.Host(new Uri("rabbitmq://production/vhost"), h =>
    {
        h.Username(_username);
        h.Password(_password);
        h.UseCluster(c =>
        {
            c.Node("server1");
            c.Node("server2");
            c.Node("server3");
        });
    });
});

bus.Start();

var endpoint = bus.GetSendEndpoint(new Uri("rabbitmq://production/vhost/my_queue"));
```

Comment: What do you mean with a logical name? A `DNS record` that resolves to a random node in the cluster?

Comment: In the sample code I posted, "production" is the logical name. It doesn't have to resolve to anything because it's only used by MassTransit to resolve send endpoints, regardless of which cluster node is connected.

Comment: Sorry just for clarification: Does it have be "production" exactly or can I fill there whatever I want (I do `cluster.First()`, I know it's a logical name, but is it fine that it stays like that)? Because I don't want to change every `Send` method in our code base.

Comment: It doesn't matter what name it is, but using the same name as one of the cluster nodes seems like a mission to confuse your engineers.

Comment: I try `bus.GetSendEndpoint(new Uri("rabbitmq://production/<exchangename>?queue=<queuename>"));`, but I get `MassTransit.EndpointNotFoundException`. There are no vhosts configured. On a single node server, this uri always worked.

Comment: I'm a step further I think, apparently uri when creating the bus (hostAddress) and uri when calling `GetSendEndpoint` must be the same. BUT because I need to connect using SSL, I put `:5671` behind `production`, then I get: ERROR. MassTransit.RabbitMqTransport.RabbitMqConnectionException: Connect failed: admin@production:5671/vhost ---> RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.BrokerUnreachableException: None of the specified endpoints were reachable ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.

Comment: Under the .UseSsl() configuration, you can specify to ignore the certificate warning.